# How to change search page url so that it still returns a page when there's no search query specified?

Tags: url-rewriting, search, urls

I want to change the search url of WordPress. Instead of `url.com/?s=searchterm` I want to change it to `url.com/search/searchterm` or `url.com/search?s=searchterm`.

On Google there's plenty of solutions for this, but most boil down to the following:

```php
function wpb_change_search_url() {
    if ( is_search() && ! empty( $_GET['s'] ) ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url( "/search/" ) . urlencode( get_query_var( 's' ) ) );
        exit();
    }   
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpb_change_search_url' );
```

This works nice, but there's one caveat: if I open the page `url.com/search`,it gives me an error message. Whilst in the old situation `url.com?s=` gave me a page with 'type your query to search this search', now it gives a now found.

So my question is: how do I modify the above code, so that the page `/search/` returns the same page as with an empty `?s=`?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Isn't that just because you've put `! empty( $_GET['s'] )` in your IF statement? Is your search page accessible when you remove that part?

**EDIT:**

Or maybe change your function to something like this (untested):

```
function wpb_change_search_url() {
    if ( is_search() ) {
        if ( isset( $_GET['s'] ) ) {
            wp_redirect( home_url( "/search/" ) . urlencode( get_query_var( 's' ) ) );
            exit();
        } else {
            wp_redirect( home_url( "/search/" ) );
            exit();
        }
    }   
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpb_change_search_url' );
```

Comment: Hey Delta, thanks for pointing that out. If I remove the condition, the search page is indeed not accessible anymore, the browser hangs.

Comment: I just tested your solution, but strange this breaks the entire search. Even `/search/searchterm` doesnt work anymore..?

Comment: Does it still break when you put the `exit();` inside the IF and ELSE? On which URL do you end up? What do you see in your network tab?

Comment: I tried your complete code snippet, I didn't try removing exit(). I must say that I now solved it by adding a page-search.php and in that file loading the search.php template. This solved it!

Comment: Thanks for your time

Comment: No problem, glad you've found a solution. Have a nice day!